# Calculate correct position for item due to difference in screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, screen, screen-resolution

Messing with an application at the moment, the application will allow you to add "notes". So you click on an element, you can add a note, and its pageX, pageY and current screen resolution is stored.

My question is how can I calculate the relative positions for other screen sizes. e.g. if its 100px 100px and the resolution is an iMac which has 2560 px. how should I display this element on a screen that has say 1140px?

Comment: You can use percentage say 10% or use vh/vw say 100vh etc.

Comment: Only problem is @AnilKumar these elements will be absolutely position with their x and y coords stored in a database. Hence my little head melter trying to figure out how to correctly position them based on screen resolutions.